# Function prototype error while implementing neural network in Python using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

We are trying to implement a Neural Network in Python. This is our code:

```
import cv
from opencv.cv import *
from opencv.highgui import *
from opencv.ml import *

def trainMachine():
    ann = CvANN_MLP()
    global ann
    fin=open("train.txt","r")
    train_sample_count=int(fin.readline())
    print "Found training file with ",train_sample_count," examples"
    trainData=cvCreateMat(train_sample_count,2,CV_32FC1)
    trainClasses=cvCreateMat(train_sample_count,1,CV_32FC1)
    sampleWts=cvCreateMat(train_sample_count,1,CV_32FC1)
    neuralLayers=cvCreateMat(4,1,CV_32SC1)
    trainData1=cvGetRows(trainData,0,train_sample_count)
        trainClasses1=cvGetRows(trainClasses,0,train_sample_count)
        sampleWts1=cvGetRows(sampleWts,0,train_sample_count)
        neuralLayers1=cvGetRows(neuralLayers,0,4)
    cvSet1D(neuralLayers1,0,cvScalar(2))
        cvSet1D(neuralLayers1,1,cvScalar(3))
        cvSet1D(neuralLayers1,2,cvScalar(3))
        cvSet1D(neuralLayers1,3,cvScalar(1))
    td=list()
    for i in range(train_sample_count):
        line = fin.readline().split()
        td.append(list())
        for num in line:
            td[i].append(float(num))
    for i in range(0,train_sample_count):
        cvSetReal2D(trainData1,i,0,td[i][0])
        cvSetReal2D(trainData1,i,1,td[i][1])
        cvSet1D(trainClasses1,i,cvScalar(td[i][2]))
        cvSet1D(sampleWts1,i,cvScalar(1))
    ann.create(neuralLayers)
    criter=cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER|CV_TERMCRIT_EPS,100000,0.001)
    params=CvANN_MLP_TrainParams(criter,0,0.01,0.05)
    ann.train(trainData,trainClasses,sampleWts,0,params)

trainmachine()
```

But we are getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ml.py", line 58, in <module>
    main()
  File "ml.py", line 52, in main
    trainMachine();
  File "ml.py", line 39, in trainMachine
    ann.train(trainData,trainClasses,sampleWts,0,params)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/opencv/ml.py", line 1310, in train
    def train(self, *args): return _ml.CvANN_MLP_train(self, *args)
NotImplementedError: Wrong number of arguments for overloaded function 'CvANN_MLP_train'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    train(CvANN_MLP *,CvMat const *,CvMat const *,CvMat const *,CvMat const *,CvANN_MLP_TrainParams,int)
    train(CvANN_MLP *,CvMat const *,CvMat const *,CvMat const *,CvMat const *,CvANN_MLP_TrainParams)
    train(CvANN_MLP *,CvMat const *,CvMat const *,CvMat const *,CvMat const *)
    train(CvANN_MLP *,CvMat const *,CvMat const *,CvMat const *)
```

We tried all the given C++ prototypes. But still there are errors.

We are actually trying to port a working implementation of neural network in C++ to Python. The problem is with the train function that is used for training our neural network.

This is the C++ source code : [neural.cpp](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:3204)

Is there any solution to this? Or please help us if the function prototype or name to be used in Python is different.

Note that the code works with Python v2.6 and OpenCV v2.1. The newer versions do not support the imported modules.